# Emulate #pragma pack(n) with attributes

Tags: c, memory-alignment, pragma

To be able to perform some systematic code transformations, I'd like to get rid of `#pragma pack` directives in my code, and replace them with local attributes, e.g. `packed, aligned(n)`.

However, the behavior I get is not exactly the same: while `sizeof` works, `offsetof` gives a different result. Here's an example:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct WITH_ATTRS {
  char c;
  double d;
} __attribute__((packed,aligned(4)));

#pragma pack(4)
struct PACK4 {
  char c;
  double d;
};

int main() {
  printf("sizeof(WITH_ATTRS) = %zu\n", sizeof(struct WITH_ATTRS));
  printf("offsetof(WITH_ATTRS, d) = %zu\n", offsetof(struct WITH_ATTRS, d));

  printf("sizeof(PACK4) = %zu\n", sizeof(struct PACK4));
  printf("offsetof(PACK4, d) = %zu\n", offsetof(struct PACK4, d));
  return 0;
}
```

GCC (5.4.0) and Clang (3.8.0) both output the same thing for me:

```
sizeof(WITH_ATTRS) = 12
offsetof(WITH_ATTRS, d) = 1
sizeof(PACK4) = 12
offsetof(PACK4, d) = 4
```

So, what I understand from this is that:

- `__attribute__((packed,aligned(4)))` leaves no gap between fields `c` and `d`, but at the end of the struct, to ensure it is a multiple of 4 (hence `sizeof == 12`);
- `#pragma pack(4)` leaves a 3-byte gap between `c` and `d`, also resulting in `sizeof == 12`.

Is there a generic way to obtain the layout of `PACK4`, but without using pragmas?

Comment: The data can be either packed or aligned. Specifying both attributes doesn't make sense for me. Your results suggest that the seconds attribute `aligned(4)` is ignored.

Comment: This question is indeed related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179748/, but the solution presented there is not complete: without a `packed` attribute, in my example the layout of the structs will not be the same. My question is more oriented as a reference of what needs to be done in practice, but perhaps editing the other question would suffice.

Comment: @harper from what I understand, the `pragma pack` directive does have this behavior of both specifying packing *and* a minimum alignment, hence the need for both attributes.

Comment: Going over this a year later -- the comments can be misleading -- the `aligned(4)` applies to the structure, not its members -- the start of the structure has to be aligned to 4 bytes, BUT the `aligned` does not apply to the members of the structure, therefore the members can start where they want (and because of the `packed` attribute, the second member starts at offset 1).